# Are there any diseases that can harm and kill flies and mosquitoes?

Tags: entomology, pathology

For decades I have heard about how flies and mosquitoes carry diseases around and infect humans and indirectly kill them in mass numbers. Somehow these diseases do not appear to harm these insects, I am not sure why. This brings me to my question, are there no diseases that infect and harm flies and mosquitoes at any stage of their life? Are there really no microbes that are out to kill them? How is this even possible? I have not found anything related to this yet through my google search.

If the flies and mosquitoes are immune to harm from every disease on earth, then why is this so? Certainly we should be able to find out the secret behind this.

Comment: The top result of my search for "pathogen mosquitoes" was [this abstract](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/17853596), which shows that there are (as expected) many disease that affect this group of flies. Adding "bacterial" as a search term yielded [this article](https://www.sciencedaily.com/releases/2019/06/190610130115.htm). Similar results are undoubtedly available for other groups of flies ...

Comment: [My answer](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/90174/is-there-any-disease-in-common-between-human-and-insects/90493#90493) to a narrower question on insect diseases contains an example of a disease of the silkworm *Bombyx mori*.

Answer (score 2):

There are plenty of diseases that affect insects, [Dicistroviridae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dicistroviridae) is one.

There are also plenty of fungal & bacterial ones, it's just that they aren't generally of concern to us so study of & information on them is somewhat light.

If you Google '**insect disease**' you'll likely just get links for human diseases they're vectors for.

If you want to find links on diseases ***OF*** insects (rather than human ones they're vectors for) try refining your search to something that's important or useful to us like bees.

[Diseases of the honey bee](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_diseases_of_the_honey_bee) is the sort of thing you'll get hits for then.